# Run N processes but never reuse the same process

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I like to run a bunch of processes concurrently but never want to reuse an already existing process. So, basically once a process is finished I like to create a new one. But at all times the number of processes should not exceed N.

I don't think I can use multiprocessing.Pool for this since it reuses processes.

How can I achieve this?

One solution would be to run N processes and wait until all processed are done. Then repeat the same thing until all tasks are done. This solution is not very good since each process can have very different runtimes.

Here is a naive solution that appears to work fine:

```py
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
import random
import os
from time import sleep


def f(q):
    print(f"{os.getpid()} Starting")
    sleep(random.choice(range(1, 10)))
    q.put("Done")


def create_proc(q):
    p = Process(target=f, args=(q,))
    p.start()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    q = Queue()

    N = 5
    for n in range(N):
        create_proc(q)

    while True:
        q.get()
        create_proc(q)
```

Comment: Or, wait until one process is done and then start one new process.

Comment: And why do you care if a new process is started or if an existing process is reused?

Comment: I'm using a third-party module that doesn't like to be run from a process that was already run. It's kinda annoying...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Pool](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool) can reuse a process a limited number of times, including one time only when you pass `maxtasksperchild=1`. You might also try `initializer` to see if you can run the picky once per process parts of your library there instead of in your pool jobs.